# How to change Spring Boot logo to Nyan Cat?

Tags: spring-boot

When I application starts I should see something similar to the following:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
```

How to change Spring Boot logo to Nyan Cat like below image?

[image]

https://spring.io/blog/2015/11/16/spring-boot-1-3-0-released

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The article already contains most information about how to do that:

> ### Color Banners
>
> Your banner.txt files can now include ANSI color codes. You can do crazy things like this:

If you look at [the Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html), you can then find more information about how to tweak the **banner.txt** file.

So, by adding a banner.txt file to the classpath, you can add your own banner. The background of a tile can be changed with `${AnsiBackground.NAME}` where `NAME` is the name of the color. The list of colors can be found in the [`AnsiColor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/ansi/AnsiColor.java) class.

Below the nyan cat you can see a small text with `:: Meow :: Running Spring Boot 1.3.0.RC1 :: \ö/`, to create such text you can use the `${spring-boot.version}` placeholder.

You can also create a banner programmatically with [`SpringApplication.setBanner()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#setBanner-org.springframework.boot.Banner-), but like I already set, it's all in the docs.

The source of the actual Nyan cat banner can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/spring-boot-4tw-uni/blob/master/spring-boot-4tw-web/src/main/resources/banner.txt), as mentioned by [Stephane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613628/stephane-nicoll).

Comment: And if you need the actual source of the banner, it is [right here](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/spring-boot-4tw-uni/blob/master/spring-boot-4tw-web/src/main/resources/banner.txt)

Answer (score 12):

Use [Spring Boot Banner Generator](https://github.com/Turbots/spring-boot-banner-gen) ; If you want to use any "image" to generate a banner for your Spring Boot application.

Copy the generated ASCII characters into /src/main/resources/banner.txt

Comment: Gets a HTTP 404